# bad quality camera source in surface view?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, surface

hello i have a problem in surface view when i want to view camera in surface view the quality of camera in surface view is very bad i want in my surface view the same resolution in my camera mobile how to check this problem this is my code

```
    package comcd.example.mohamed_card_scanner.live;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.StringBuilderPrinter;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.Text;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView cameraView;
    TextView textView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID:
            {
                if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);



        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);


        TextRecognizer textRecongnizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        if (!textRecongnizer.isOperational()) {
            Log.w("MainActivity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");

        } else {


            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecongnizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .setRequestedFps(2.0f)

                    .build();

           // (1280, 1024)


            //









            //





            cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

                    try {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    RequestCameraPermissionID);
                            return;
                        }
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                    cameraSource.stop();

                }
            });

            textRecongnizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
                @Override
                public void release() {

                }

                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                    final SparseArray<TextBlock> items= detections.getDetectedItems();

                    if(items.size()!=0)
                    {
                        textView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                                for(int i=0;i<items.size();++i)
                                {
                                    TextBlock item=items.valueAt(i);
                                    stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                                }

                                textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
























}
```